# command not found when executed from jenkins, but runs on mac agent

Tags: jenkins, nuget

I have Jenkins set up on a Windows machine, with a mac slave configured.

When I run the command `nuget` directly from terminal, it works. However when I try running the `nuget` command from Jenkins as a executable shell, I get command not found

```
[iOS Build] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/hr/b_p9skp53178b45895w2htw80000gn/T/hudson278562289764277217.sh
+ nuget restore '/Users/a/Jenkins/workspace/iOS Build/App/Acquaint.Native.sln'
/var/folders/hr/b_p9skp53178b45895w2htw80000gn/T/hudson278562289764277217.sh: line 2: nuget: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I already have the directory where `nuget` resides configured in the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe:

- `echo $PATH` within your job to ensure it's configured as you expect when the job runs.
- try including the full path to nuget. run `/usr/local/bin/nuget restore...` (or wherever nuget is found) instead of `nuget restore...` to determine if it's really a PATH issue.